# Plone and dexterity custom index

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity

I've created a custom folderish content type (bobo) using dexterity and a custom index (ibobo) in the catalog.
I'm able to put images inside bobo with no problem.
The problem is the images are being indexed in ibobo and I don't want this.
The ibobo index is working well when I change bobo data but the images keep the old data in its ibobo index.
It is crazy because images don't have ibobo index.
How can I avoid images indexing in this case?
Thank you.

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: All the "ibobo" and "bobo" talk is confusing me :)

Comment: Is there by any chance an "ibobo" method in a custom class for the bobo content type? If so, you're being bit by spammish acquisition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want use a dedicated index for you content type and avoid indexing anything else into your index.

You can achieve this by

1. Create a custom indexer using `plone.indexer`for you content type interface.
2. Create an another indexer using `plone.indexer` for `zope.interface.Interface` that only to raises `AttributeError`.

That should stop the default indexing and only your dedicated content type gets indexed into your index.

The issue is, that for historical reasons Plone (Zope2/ZCatalog) indexes try to index everything, which either has an attribute with the name of the index (or its configured indexable attribute) or can acquire a such attribute using acquisition.

Comment: Thank you, Asko! Now I know what I need to do. I'm sorry but I did it using only zope interface :(.. I need to move it to an add on, but please tell me the best way and tools to start developing dexterity products. Thank you again, Bye.

Comment: Yes, a filesystem product is the only way to make a custom index that does not have the issue you reported in your question (indexes made through Zope interface can have your issue). Plone docs have a few tutorials: http://docs.plone.org/external/tutorial.todoapp/docs/index.html http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/prerequisite.html http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/indexing.html